# the flute section keeps passing notes

Tags: knowledge, cipher, music

(_ˇ෴ˇ)_⟋

(づ◕‿◕ )づ日    ٩(◕‿◕)۶

The band director is tired of the flutes passing notes in class, but he can't tell what the notes say. Here is one of the messages.

2 10 - 1 2 3 10 - 1 2 10 - 1 2 10 - 1 2 3 10 - 1 2 3 4 10- 1 2 3 4 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 6 - 1 2 3 10 - 2 10 - 1 2 3 4 8 9 10

What are they saying?

Hint:

> The band director suspects the note was an insult, but he can't verify since he can't read it.

Comment: I assume that rot13(gur svefg gjb yvarf ner arrqrq gb fbyir gur chmmyr, be abg arprffnevyl?)

Comment: Probably not. rot13(frrzf zber yvxr grkg neg.)

Comment: @Someone Oh okay, rot13(gung jbhyq zbfg qrsvavgryl pyrne hc zl pbashfvba gou)

Comment: My apologies, the text art means nothing.

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA Lol that's okay, rot13(vg'f jung V hfhnyyl guvax bs svefg jura V frr gung glcr bs fghss yby)

Comment: rot13(Vs V vagrecerg gur ahzoref nf svatrevatf, V trg PNOONR TNPR. Cyhf, fbzr bs gur svatrevatf qba'g znxr gung zhpu frafr.)

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA I guess what I'm asking is, do you verify all the numbers are currently correct?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess was that the numeric values were

> binary place values

but I later decided they might be something closer to the theme, like

> flute note fingerings

Either way, I decided that whatever the numeric values were, they had to

> go together to form letters, because otherwise the messages were only capable of having up to 10 letters in a message

This meant that the provided note was something of the form

> ABCCBD EBAD

But analysis down that road didn't provide anything particularly obvious or meaningful, although my favorite solution that fits the form (but not the puzzle) was:

> FERRET LEFT

**EDIT**

Given the insights of @DanDan0101, I believe the answer to be:

> CABBAGE FACE

even though this requires that

> The note is missing a fingering (likely 1 2 3 4 10) for G and has an unexpected fingering for F.  I would have expected the puzzle to instead read 2 10 - 1 2 3 10 - 1 2 10 - 1 2 10 - 1 2 3 10 - 1 2 3 4 10 - 1 2 3 4 8 9 10 // 1 2 3 4 5 10 - 1 2 3 10 - 2 10 - 1 2 3 4 8 9 10

Comment: rot13(Lbh'er ba gur evtug ebnq jvgu gur svatrevatf guvat...)

Comment: Ohhh no, yeah, this puzzle is filled with mistakes, but yes, you got the idea. The numbers encode flute fingerings, which correspond to notes.